# Different types of Navigation controller/view/bars

Tags: ios

Can somebody explain the difference pros/cons of following things related to navigation in iOS.

Just in case, if it's relevant. I use XCode 4.5 and xibs.

1) If I choose a view in Interface Builder and choose "Attributes inspector", there is an item called "Top Bar" and I can choose "Navigation Bar" in there.

I did some experimenting. It's displayed in Interface Builder, but looks like it doesn't influence anything in runtime. Am I missing something

2) In Interface Builder, I can drag and drop "Navigation Controller" from Objects list and add some View in it.

3) In Interface Builder, I can drag and drop "Navigation Bar" and put it on some view

It's not clear for me what is the difference between item #2 and #3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The things that you can add in the Simulated Metrics section are just to help you lay things out in IB, it doesn't actually add them.

2) & 3) A navigation controller allows you to do push and pop transitions between view controllers that are embedded in it. It takes care of changing the titles in the navigation bar and the text in the back button. You can't do a push segue or use pushViewController:animated: in code if your controllers aren't embedded in a navigation controller. A navigation bar is just a UI element that normally goes at the top of the screen and can contain navigation items. By itself, it doesn't do anything. You have to write the code that takes care of titles and button text. Adding a navigation bar to a view doesn't make it so you can do a push, only embedding it in the UINavigationController allows you to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Let me answer all the question together by showing a simple method. Just use StoryBoards because they are really simple and shows more clearly what is happening.

All you need to do is to select the view controller (let us say your primary view controller) and go to the menu then Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller. It will all make sense then.